# is it secure that all capacitor apps use localhost as an origin

Tags: security, webview, localhost, indexeddb, capacitor

since all capacitor apps run on a WebView and use localhost as an origin does this means that the data stored in the WebView's localStorage or indexeddb is shared between hybrid apps. Since the origin is the same for all apps...

Comment: The data is unique per app on both iOS and Android, it’s not shared within apps, it’s tied to the bundle identifier/package name

Answer (score 0):

you may use @capaciors/storage to target native storage and for secure storage you can also use the comunity plugin secure-storage

import { SecureStoragePlugin } from 'capacitor-secure-storage-plugin';

https://github.com/martinkasa/capacitor-secure-storage-plugin

if you want to use a paid implementation there is Ionics secure storage as well

[https://ionic.io/docs/secure-storage#:~:text=Secure%20Storage%20Ionic%20Secure%20Storage%20is%20a%20cross-platform,when%20used%20with%20the%20Ionic%20Storage%20utility%20library](https://ionic.io/docs/secure-storage#:%7E:text=Secure%20Storage%20Ionic%20Secure%20Storage%20is%20a%20cross-platform,when%20used%20with%20the%20Ionic%20Storage%20utility%20library).

Comment: yes this replaces localStorage but it can't replace indexeddb, I was interested in a package called dexie js which a wrapper for indexeddb, which gives you a powerful database with querying capabilities in the browser, 

I was wondering since all capacitor apps share the same origin do they share the same data and effect each other accidentally, this was my first security flag.

Comment: my second security flag when I found out that the operating system (Anroid or iOS) can reclaim the storage space and remove you webview's data....Even though IndexedDB wiith dexje js is a nice database in the browser/webview, its not secure because of those concerns.

Comment: i think you would then use ionics secure storage, SecureStoragePlugin uses the keychain in ios but for android it doesnt use secure preferences, instead it encrypts into indexdb same as in web i think